# How to Add variable from code.gs to Audio src?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Need help to fix this code please

I want to Add the value of my Variable to the src of my audio, so that the text to speech will read the value from my spreadsheet as text.

```
  function checkCalls() {
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (columnH) {
  var div = document.getElementById('call2');
  var newvar = getColumnH();
  div.src = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=en&q=" + newvar + "NEXT+CUSTOMER+PLEASE"
    for (var i = 0; i < columnH.length; i++) {

      // if there's a difference and it's a call, notify the user
      if (lastTime[i] !== columnH[i] && columnH[i] === "Call") {
        notify();
      }
    }

    // store results for next time
    lastTime = columnH;

    console.log(lastTime);

    // poll again in x miliseconds
    var x = 1000; // 1 second
    window.setTimeout(checkCalls, x);
  }).getColumnH();
}
```

newvar is from my code.gs

```
function getColumnH() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DASHBOARD");
// get the values in column H and turn the rows into a single values
var newvar = getColumnA();
console.log(newvar);
return sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function (row) { return row[0]; 
});
}

function getColumnA(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("CONTROLS");
var r =  s.getRange("A1")
var lastvalue = r.getValues();
return lastvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Div is not an audio element you should use Audio Element instead

By seeing your code `var div = document.getElementById('call2');`

The correct use of HTML5 Audio generated should be:

```
<audio controls>
  <source id="call2" src="added programatically" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Or

```
<audio id="call2" src="added programatically" controls type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

If this is not the case and div means exactly as is, then you should change your HTML structure and make use of the above mentioned. Here's an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Otherwise the URL generated for the source is not correct.

Comment: Hi Sir! I just need to get the value of "var newvar = getColumnA();" to be added on this src "div.src = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=en&q=" + newvar + "NEXT+CUSTOMER+PLEASE". By the way the id of my audio tag is "div". i will change it because it confused me also.

Comment: As far as I understand `getColumnH()` throws an error, if so can you please share the error you are facing? Anyway, div is just a container which doesn't automatically reproduce the HTML5 audio.